# hibernate query not producing results

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to list all records form a user table.

each time I send the request I get this log

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.creation_date,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.full_name,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.updated_date,
        u1_0.username 
    from
        user u1_0
```

but this query is not returning any results

this is the result I get from postman http request

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

I have a user entity like this:

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String fullName;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date updatedDate;
}
```

a repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

a controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public List<User> listAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

and this is my [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1RAr.png)

Comment: do you even have any data in that table?..

Comment: i do have 5 records in that table

Comment: i updated the post and added the response i get form postman

Comment: This is almost always because of things like the table being used from Java differs from that used from the external SQL call because different schema/user being used. Are you using same credentials for both. Another possible reason is the records aren’t committed. Log out and into your DB client and check records. Next thing to do up the debugging to see the SQL - https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Comment: i used intellij debugger and everything is alright the `userRepository.findAll()` method is equal to all the records but the rest controller is not returning the results